# Getting NoSuchMethodError in Kafka Consumer v0.10.0.1

Tags: websphere-liberty, kafka-consumer-api, message-hub

I am trying to move to KafkaClient 0.10.0.1 from 0.9.0.0. The code is working fine in production with 0.9.0.0. Now the same code in development platform throwing exception when a consumer is started with following exception
    javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.subscribe(Ljava/util/List;)V (loaded from file:/home/vcap/app/wlp/usr/shared/config/lib/global/kafka-clients-0.10.0.1.jar by com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader@7a0d5027) called from class com.ibm.b2b.msghub.helper.AbstractB2BConsumer (loaded from file:/home/vcap/app/wlp/usr/shared/config/lib/global/B2BBlueMixLib-1.0.jar by com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader@7a0d5027).

Madhu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client API has slightly changed between Kafka 0.9 and 0.10.

The definition of KafkaConsumer.subscribe() has changed. The first argument is now of type Collection instead of List.

This was done to make the API more consistent as now most (all?) calls take a Collection object whereas before it was a mix of several types.

Comment: Thanks Mickael for your response. I tried casting the list to Collection<String>. It did not work. So I used the subscribe method that uses Pattern object. I am facing the same issue for ConsumerRebalanceListener where I am implementing kafkaConsumer.seekToEnd  for method onPartitionsAssigned                          Collection<TopicPartition> cur = Arrays.asList(partition);
                         kafkaConsumer.seekToEnd(cur);

Comment: For the above code I am getting compilation error: [ERROR] required: org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition[]
[ERROR] found: java.util.Collection<org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition>
[ERROR] reason: varargs mismatch; java.util.Collection<org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition> cannot be converted to org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition

Comment: A List is already a Collection so no need to cast. It looked more like a dependency issues. Either you built against the wrong level of Kafka or you have the wrong Jar version on your appserver.

Same for seekToEnd(). It now takes a Collection. But from your output it looks like it was expecting the old type (TopicPartition varargs) !